# Algolia - AutoComplete with Suggestion + Search Results Page - NextJS

Tags: next.js, algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch

Am implementing the Algolia search in my NextJS app. I have the datasource and indices already setup. What am trying to setup is something like what Gucci is doing in their search. Gucci is using Algolia for their search functionality.

[image]

I tried using the [react-instantsearch-dom](https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch) package of Algolia. And I updated my `/pages/_app.js` file like this(only relevant code is written here):

```
/**
 *      /pages/_app.js
 * 
 */

//-------- Algolia
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import { InstantSearch } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const searchClient = algoliasearch( 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy' );
//-------- /Algolia

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <>
            <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName={ 'abc_test_products' }>
                <Component {...pageProps} />                                
            </InstantSearch>   
        </>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

This way I could use the components of `react-instantsearch-dom` anywhere.

Am confused at three things here.

---

**Doubt 1:**

How can I pass the algolia query and filters to the search results page like here and display the results using the components : https://www.gucci.com/us/en/st/newsearchpage?facetFilters=categoryLevel1_en%3AChildren&searchString=handbags&search-cat=header-search

[image]

So basically when the user clicks one of the algolia search suggestions(from the dropdown after clicking the search box at the top right corner of the page), they are taken to a search results page and there it seems like Algolia search is instantiated and displays the results.

---

**Doubt 2:**

How can I display the auto suggestions and product images side by side?

[image]

---

**Doubt 3:**

Displaying dynamic filter/refinement options. I understood that if there's a `brand` attribute in our Algoia indices/dataset, I can include that in the search filter like this:

```
<RefinementList attribute="brand" />
```

But if there are different attribute that I want to display the refinement list, say "Color", "Brand", etc. how would I display the title of the refinement option and the list dynamically from the search results.

---

Answer (score 0):

Your UI example looks like a mash-up of a Query Suggestions panel on the left and a Hits list on the right. You can customize what a `hit` looks like before you render to get the image in there. And the filter menus automatically update as the user filters.

I haven't tried to get the query params into the URL, that would be interesting. I think you'd have to add `useRouter` into your Next page and then push the Algolia params onto the string using `onClick`.

Below is an example I built, maybe it helps you:

```js
const Search = () => {

  const Hit = ({ hit }) => {
    return (
      <HitContainer>
        <span>{hit.type}</span>
        <h2><a href={hit.path}>{hit.title}</a></h2>
        {
          hit.content &&
            <p>{ `${hit.content.substring(0,150)} ...` }</p>
        }
        <hr />
      </HitContainer>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
        <InstantSearch
          searchClient={ AlgoliaReactClient } 
          indexName="MAINSITE" >
          
          <CustomSearchBox 
            translations={{
              submitTitle: 'Submit your search query.',
              resetTitle: 'Clear your search query.',
              placeholder: 'What are you looking for?',
            }}
          />
          <HitsAndFilters>
            <AllFilters>
              <h3>Topics</h3>
              <FilterMenu
                attribute="topics" 
                limit={5}
                showMore
              />
              <h3>Locations</h3>
              <FilterMenu
                attribute="locations" 
                limit={5}
                showMore
              />
            </AllFilters>
            <AllHits hitComponent={Hit} />
          </HitsAndFilters>
        </InstantSearch>
      </>
    )
  }
```